# Unable to add Site Page under SharePoint Online Site Pages Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, sitepages, pages, classic-experience

I am using the SharePoint Online Classic site. I need to add Modern Site Page under the Site Pages library.

I have tried to add a new page under the Site Pages library. *But the add **Site Page** option is missing while adding a new page*.

Please check the below screenshot for more details.
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to enable the Site Page option under the Site Pages document library?

Can anyone help me with the same?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the follow ways:
1, Enable "Allow users to create site pages"
Go to **SharePoint admin center -->Settings-->classic settings page-->**
Ensure "**Allow users to create site pages**" is checked.
Restart your browser and re-login, then see if the problem is solved.

2, Add the content type to the library
In Site Pages Library,
go to "**Library Settings**"-->
In the **Content Type** Section, click on "**Add from existing content types**"-->
Search for "**Site Page**" from the list (you can simply select one item and press "S" on your keyboard to take you to all the content types starting from S) -->
Select "**Site Page**" and click Add and then click on OK.
Go back to Site Pages Library, click on New and you should be able to create Site Page now.